# Exporting PostgreSQL table to FileGDB: wkbUnknown layer geometry type

Tags: postgis, esri-geodatabase, ogr

I'm attempting to export a PostGIS (1.5.3) database table as a File geodatabase using the new FileGDB OGR / GDAL 1.9.0 driver:

```
$ ogr2ogr -overwrite -sql "SELECT * from db_pts LIMIT 1" \
    -f "FileGDB" /tmp/test.gdb \
    PG:"host='HOST' dbname='DB'"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1: Error (-1): FGDB layers cannot be created with a wkbUnknown layer geometry type.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation from sql statement.
```

The geometry column in the table I'm exported is set up properly and is in the `geometry_columns` table.  I think the problem has to do with the way the `-sql` option is returning the layer geometry type.  For example, accessing the same database table with `ogrinfo`:

```
$ ogrinfo -ro -sql "SELECT * from db_allobs LIMIT 1" PG:"host=HOST dbname='DB'"
Layer name: sql_statement
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
...
OGRFeature(sql_statement):0
...
  POINT (-151.472835 69.635245)
```

It's as though the query doesn't look in `geometry_columns` when building the layer, but later, when exporting the rows it knows that the geometry being exported is a `POINT` (in this case).

When I use a similar command to produce a shapefile, all is well, including the layer geometry, which is set to point.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the bad form, but the answer is to add the ``-nlt`` option, which allows you to set the layer type when ``-sql`` is used.  I found this at: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4186

In other words:

    ``ogr2ogr -overwrite -sql "SELECT * from db_pts LIMIT 1" -f "FileGDB" /tmp/test.gdb PG:"host='HOST' dbname='DB'" -nlt POINT``
     

Sorry for the traffic.

Comment: you should put this as an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: I agree with Ragi, and it means you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for the bad form, but the answer is to add the `-nlt` option, which allows you to set the layer type when `-sql` is used.  I found this at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4186.

In other words:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -sql "SELECT * from db_pts LIMIT 1" \
        -f "FileGDB" /tmp/test.gdb \
        PG:"host='HOST' dbname='DB'" -nlt POINT
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it may help someone else. I had an issue when converting the SRID. I was able to resolve this by casting the geometry column to the specific type. ie:

```
SELECT st_transform(g.geom, 998998)::geometry(Point,998998) AS wkb_geometry
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was having problems with a view with no SRID nor GEOMETRY TYPE in my geometry_columns view. Defining the view the way you say, solved everything!