# Postgis change geometry type to Polygon

Tags: postgis

I have a table that has its geometry type as geometry and I need to convert it to Polygon for `ogr2ogr` to read it. Can't figure this out.

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiPolygon, 102689);

error 

    ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)
    SQL state: 22023
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(Polygon, 102689);

ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
********** Error **********

ERROR: Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
SQL state: 22023
```

[image]

Comment: Ogr2ogr should be totally happy with reading generic geometries. Please tell more about your use case and what problems you have.

Comment: @user30184 this is my post. I updated all the SRID's and it still craps out on me  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234164/ogr2ogr-export-postgresql-to-esri-file-gdb-wkbunknown-layer-geometry-type/234706#234706

Comment: First thing that I would do is to make an own ogr2ogr command for each layer instead of trying to convert the whole database with one shot.

Comment: okay il do that but it already tells me which layer stops the process and why

Comment: I would like to know how to change the geometry type regardless

Comment: I would try something like `ogr2ogr -f gpkg -sql "select * from oak_all_buffers where OGR_GEOMETRY='POLYGON'" output.gpkg PG:input_string -nlt POLYGON`. I wrote intentionally GeoPackage as outputformat because I do not know file geodatabase.

Comment: specifying the -nlt polygon works for one layer at a time, but correlating this back to my original problem is I cant specify -nlt Polygon because I have 18 tables that are either points or polygons...

Comment: If you have multipolygons you must explode then for getting polygons. Ogr2ogr has an documented option -explodecollections for that purpose http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. With PostGIS you will use ST_Dump http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html.

Comment: Make a script or a batch file.

Comment: To convert a multipolygon column to a polygon geometry column... HIS: ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(Polygon, 102689);
YOURS: ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(Polygon, 102689); There is no difference in what Ziggy reported and the solution. I have the same issue converting a MultiPolygon to Polygon geometry. What am I missing.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148176)

Comment: @user9491577 use (ST_Dump(geom)).geom

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can change the Column Type to Polygon with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(Polygon, 102689);
```

or change to MultiPolygon if you have mixed Polygon/Multipolygon *(credits @Vesanto)*

```
ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiPolygon, 102689) using ST_Multi(geom);
```

Comment: check my edit! this did work for some of the layers

Comment: ALTER TABLE oak_all_buffers ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiPolygon, 102689) using ST_Multi(geom);

Comment: Quick and dirty way to generate UPDATE statement text for all dim > 2 geometries: `SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || f_table_schema || '.' || f_table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || f_geometry_column || ' TYPE geometry(' || "type" || ', ' || srid || ') USING ST_Force2D(' || f_geometry_column || ');' query FROM geometry_columns WHERE coord_dimension > 2;`.   Could be made a lot prettier with a function.

Comment: How to convert multipoint to point?

I try with 

'ALTER TABLE geodb.v_rete_prova
ALTER COLUMN geometry TYPE geometry(MultiPointZ,3003) 
USING ((st_dump(geometry)).geom::geometry(pointz,3003));' but it doesn't work

Comment: what if i want multi srid geometries in the same table ?