# Set SRID for mixed geometry type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, geometry, srid

I have a geometry column with mixed geometries like polygon, multi polygon. I am trying to set SRID for it using below query but I get the below error. What type of geometry has to be given when we have multi polygon and polygon type in one column?

Query:-

```
ALTER TABLE geo_table
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(POLYGON,4326) USING ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(geometry,3857),4326)
```

Error:-

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)
```

Comment: I would force them to be all be multi using st_multi. then run your SRID command with multipolygon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgis change geometry type to Polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234784/postgis-change-geometry-type-to-polygon)

Comment: A generic geometry type "geometry" accepts all kind of geometries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the generic `geometry` type. Also make sure to spell the proper column name in the `using`

```sql
ALTER TABLE geo_table
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(geometry,4326) 
    USING ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(geom ,3857),4326);
```